# PHP and MySQL - Is there a way to get embedded/nested objects in response?

Tags: php, mysql, oop, object, nested

I figure SQL probably isn't this advanced - or perhaps it's a limitation of PHP + MySQL, but please consider this scenario:

I have a user table, and a profile table.

I want to get the user by their ID. The user table has a foreign key reference to the profile table. Can I somehow join the tables such that the response would produce an object like this: (Note: With enough PHP this is doable, but I want to keep it to a single MySQL query)

```
user_id: 1
username: foo
profile => first_name: Foo
           last_name: Bar
           picture: foo.jpg
email: foo@example.com
```

This is possible using LINQ in C#, I'm just wondering if there's an equivalent for PHP.

Answer (score -1):

I think what you need to do here is a simple JOIN.

```
SELECT users.*, profiles.*
FROM `users`
LEFT JOIN profiles
ON users.id = profiles.user_id
WHERE users.id = '$user_id_var'
LIMIT 1;
```

That will append the profile data do your user, but won't require profile data to return a positive result.

You will need to be careful to take conflicting keys into consideration, but this query should get you on the right path.

Comment: Hmm, that got me thinking. This isn't exactly what I wanted (I had already considered a join) - because it turns the response into a flat object as opposed to something multi-dimensional. However, if I then have a PHP class with which I can bind the profile data separate from the user data then that might be good enough. If no one has a better solution then this is the answer.

Comment: If you have multiple profiles per user id, then you will get them in adjacent rows of SQL result, but if there is 1:1 correspondence with id's and profiles, your data is already flat -logically- ;) .

Comment: Ahh, good point. Well, I'd still like it separated in the object but I can do that in PHP. Should make for some very easy to read objects.. Thanks for this.

Comment: I'm not 100% certain this will make sense, and I'm sure some certified SQL DBA will want to punch me, but I believe you won't be able to accomplish your "multi-dimensional" result with just SQL.  SQL will want to return rows, and whatever I can fit into that row.  A column in a row can contain an array/hash/whatever, but that would be packed by your processor (PHP/Ruby/Perl).

Comment: I guess this is where NoSQL comes in. This should work for my purposes though.